# Blank grid when running Google maps activity + no Emulator available to test Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I Have installed Goggle APIs for Andorid 4.4 and set the build target of my project to it.
However there is no emulator device available as I cannot set the Target on the emulator to Google API, only to android API 19. Is there way around this?

When running the project on a actual device I only get a blank map and the following stack trace:

> Couldn't get connection factory client 01-08 11:51:23.775:
>   W/System.err(14134): IOException processing: 26 01-08 11:51:23.780:
>   W/System.err(14134): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3 01-08
>   11:51:23.780: W/System.err(14134):    at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
>   01-08 11:51:23.780: W/System.err(14134):  at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
>   01-08 11:51:23.780: W/System.err(14134):  at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
>   01-08 11:51:23.780: W/System.err(14134):  at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
>   01-08 11:51:23.780: W/System.err(14134):  at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
>   01-08 11:51:23.785: W/System.err(14134):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856

I have set my manifest as follows:

```
<!-- need to render map woth using OPen GL ES ver 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyBDJvZAvBXY64_6QSZRWGY66T0kxN6Ur8Y" />
```

Any input appreciated.
I am using ADT v22.3.0-887826.
Cheers
Ciaran

Udate:
Finally realised I and to add the Google play library to the project(wasn't mentioned in book i am using!), i also changed my XML file according to Google tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key as bellow, not instead of a grid i am getting a blank map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Wondering if my key is the issue, when I submitted on the google i did with my SHA-1 fingerprint;packagename, do i need to add package name AND app name here or just package name??

Comment: use google map V2 for android, I guess you are using older version

Comment: Try this answer, it might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager/19354359#19354359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use google map v2 because google map v1 has been deprecated. Try my answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830610/android-google-map-api-v2-unfortunately-application-has-stopped-force-clos/20840757#20840757).

Comment: have maps2 declared in my manifest si I'm assuming i am using map 2:  <!-- google map api key -->
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBDJvZAvBXY64_6QSZRWGY66T0kxN6Ur8Y"/>
    </application>

Comment: i didn't quite understand your code or war it is doing exactly, please see the edit to check if my changes are achieving something similar

Comment: thanks that worked. Is MapView completed depreciated in v2 so map can only be obtained as a obj of GoogleMap?